# AVL comparison method, correct approach or not?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, avl-tree

I'm using a small `AVL` tree library and as you know, you need to define a comparison method for your `AVL` tree nodes. Libraries pass `AVL` keys to this method for sorting elements of tree. Here is the syntax of comparison method:

```
int compare(const void* l, const void* r)
{
}
```

This function should return a positive value when `l>r`, zero when `l==r` and negative value when `l<r` and this method's efficiency has a tremendous effect on `AVL`'s efficiency.

Now assume that `AVL` tree keys are `uint32_t`. A simple method is using following compare function:

```
int compare(const void* l, const void* r)
{
    if (*(uint32_t*)l > *(uint32_t*)r)
        return 1;
    if (*(uint32_t*)l < *(uint32_t*)r)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

But this method's amortized running time is a disaster on well balanced data because of **high chance of jump prediction fails on `if` statements**. I normally write this comparison as following:

```
int compare(const void* l, const void* r)
{
    return *(uint32_t*)l - *(uint32_t*)r;
    // if you want to overcome underflow in subtraction, you can write it like this:
    // return (int64_t)*(uint32_t*)l - (int64_t)*(uint32_t*)r;
    // But this will not solve problem with casting to int for returning result
}
```

Which is a huge efficiency improvement. But considering return type of `int`, I wonder if overflow on casting from `uint32_t` to `int` or underflow on subtraction (or any other bigger key data size in general case) may cause incorrect tree structure. If your key values take up to 31 bits, every thing works perfectly with this compare method. But if keys take up to 32 bits, things will get tricky. For example see following results:

```
`l` points to value | `r` points to value | result
--------------------------------------------------
2                   |1                    | 1
2                   |0xFFFFFFFF           | 3
```

This means this compare function searches both value in same side of tree, while in the first case `l>r` and second one is `l<r` considering both keys as unsigned values.

I wonder if using this compare method may not result in finding a node in `AVL` tree when node really exists. what do you think? If this method may fail to find nodes, what highly efficient compare method will be suitable for these situations?

Best Regards

Comment: *" I wonder if overflow on casting from uint32_t to int"* - I'd first be concerned about *underflow* in your unsigned subtraction where `r` is greater than `l`. It will "work" (it isn't UB) , but it will assuredly *not* deliver the answer you're looking for. That alone makes that mechanism a poor candidate.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated question for your comment, but underflow in subtraction can be solved by casting data to a bigger data type for example like this: `(int64_t)*(uint32_t*)l - (int64_t)*(uint32_t*)r`. But casting in method result cannot be solved. and I'm open to all highly efficient methods. :)

Comment: Have you actually measured that the comparison function is a disaster?  Compared to the wrong answer you get from the replacement, correct code outperforms incorrect code.  You'd have to do something dramatic like cast the values to `int64_t` before subtracting so that you get the signed result you want, and you'd need to convert back to `int` (from `int64_t`) carefully to get the correctly signed result.  Are you sure that's quicker the original code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler casting to `int64_t` have almost no effect, because almost every processor right now is 64-bit. As for speed, I check based on number of jumps in assembly code. even though optimization can create miracles and in my mentioned example clang creates jump free assembly code, but with a little more complex code, you see a lot of jumps.

Comment: Note that this problem goes away if you use boolean comparison functions like the STL does

Comment: @MattTimmermans can you give a small example? just remember that I cannot change the interface of comparison method, because it is defined by library.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were writing the AVL tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, UB-free method of comparison is as follows:

```
int compare (void* a, void* b)
{
    unsigned int aa = *(unsigned int*)a;
    unsigned int bb = *(unsigned int*)b;
    return (aa > bb) - (aa < bb);
}
```

On x86, gcc compiles it to this rather efficient code (with -O2):

```
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  xor eax, eax
  cmp ecx, edx
  seta al
  sbb eax, 0
  ret
```

Comment: great results. :) But I wonder if this method is extendable to comparing more values. for example if keys are `a`, `b`, `c` which are passed through an structure to compare function(if `a` is equal then check `b` and if `b` equal then check `c`), is it still logical to use a method like this instead of `if` or not.

Comment: @Afshin You can eliminate conditionals, e,g. `(a ? b : c)` should be the same as `(b * (a!=0) + c *(a==0))`. This will likely compile to jump-free code, and you can use this to build lexicographical struct comparison. But you always need to measure, compare and decide on a case by case basis, because in some cases straight `if`s might be faster.